# Voltage regulator with heatsink gets overheated

Tags: voltage-regulator, heat, heatsink

First of, I'm sorry if I'm using the wrong terms or if I'm pointing out something that is obvious to most, this is not my profession, it's only a hobby.

I have an input voltage of 12V 5A which is needed for a water pump. I'm trying to use the same source too drive a Raspberry PI Zero W together with a bunch of sensors. To lower the voltage to 5V I'm using a voltage regulator, L78S05CV, which I had lying around. It should be able to give me 2A but currently I'm only needing about 0.27A.

The voltage regulator has a heatsink with a thermal resistance of 29 °C/W and the regulator has a thermal resistance from junction to case of 5 °C/W (Rthj-a of 50 °C/W). The regulator dissipate around 1.89W ((12 - 5) * 0.27), which would mean around 64 °C ((29 + 5) * 1.89). Assuming an air temperature of 25 °C it should end up at around 90 °C. The regulator should have a operating junction temperature of up to 150 °C.
Still I do belive that the regulator gets overheated after some time, I can see a drop in voltage to about 2.5V.

I am trying to understand the math here, to see if I need another heatsink with a better thermal resistance or if I should just look at other alternatives.

I have read several other responses to similar threads, but too be honest, the answers is a bit out of my league.

Comment: Resistor? Do you mean regulator? The whole heat dissipation thing relies on the heatsink having heat removed so that the local ambient temperature *can* be assumed to be 25 degC. If this does not happen then *local* ambient rises a bit then the chip then rises a bit (in response as you would expect) then local ambient rises a bit more and you have a problem.

Comment: Nice catch, editing.

Comment: Unless you're doing something funny, your output is 5 volts, so power is (12-5)/.27, which gives a final temp of about 114.

Comment: This is really a role for a switching regulator, not a linear one.

Comment: Please also include the Rthj-c thermal resistance of the capsule.

Comment: @winny: Hmm, Rthj-c is 5 degrees, am I missing something? Rthj-a is 50 degrees.

Comment: Instead of '25C', your heatsink calculation should allow for the temperature to be hot next to the heatsink; without a fan, that could be 60 to 85C without damaging nearby components.    In a hot room, even WITH a fan, 25C is an optimistic value.

Comment: Oh! So that’s where the 29+5 came from. Carry on!

Comment: @Whit3rd The specified thermal resistance of the heatsink *should* be the resistance between component case and ambient *without* a fan unless indicated otherwise. The specification usually requires sufficient airflow from convection, though, so it does not apply if convection is impeded by a tiny case or components nearby. If the regulator operates inside a case (even a big one allowing internal convection), the ambient temperature is the temperature inside the case, which in fact might be a lot higher than ambient outside the case.

Comment: @Ganhammar Did you add thermal compound or a sil pad to get the heat from the case to the heatsink? If not, you might have a high thermal resistance there. If you use a sil pad, look up its thermal resistance. You most likely cannot neglect it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, you wrote P=U/I.  Also, how did you end up at 114?

Comment: @OskarSkog - Voltage drop is 7 volts rather than 5, or a factor of 1.4. 1.4 x 64 is 89.6. Plus 25 is about 115. So I guess i hit 4 rather than 5. Not a significant error, given the roughness of the other approximations.

Comment: @Michael Karcher - I did not add any compound or a sil, so thanks for that tip! I also think that what you are mentioning regarding airflow might be a big factor! Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that drop in 7805 replacement switching regulators are available for not a lot of money.  Pin to pin compatible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast.  Nobody said it was a 5V drop.  The original calculations sreem correct.

Comment: @KH - Do you have an example of a switching regulator that would do the trick? Thanks!

Comment: @Ganhammar I think the ones I've been using are [murata ones from digikey.](https://www.digikey.ca/en/product-highlight/c/cui/dc-switching-regulators)  They were about 3 to 5 bucks, and I've since ordered similar knock offs from aliexpress to performance test.

Comment: @KH - Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear regulator is not the best solution when there's a big difference between the input (12V) and output voltage (5V). 7V are dissipated in heat.

If possible try to use a switching regulator.

If you want to keep the linear regulator you can attach an old pc fan in the heatsink(from a hard disk or graphic card for example) and use thermal paste between the regulator and the heatsink.

The improvement is dramatic.

Answer (score 1):

Put a power resistor between the 12V supply and input to the 7805.

This will transfer the excess wattage from the 7805 to the resistor.

I used a [Yageo 5.1Ω SQP500JB-5R1](http://www.yageo.com/NewPortal/yageodocoutput?fileName=/pdf/throughhole/Yageo_LR_SQP_NSP_2013.pdf) resistor for a 12V powered 7805 with a 300 mA load in a product I manufactured for 18 years. No field service issues ever.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but I already bought a switching regulator and a bigger heatsink. Will probably use the switching regulator in the end.

Comment: The switching regulator is the way to go if efficiency is of any concern.  Linear is the way to go if reliability is a concern.  With the Yageo resistor the heatsink is not needed.